# Websphere - Rest call - Certificate chaining error

Tags: java, rest, ssl, websphere

i try to access a rest service with NTLM authentication via httpcomponents in Websphere.

I receive the following error:

```
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.n: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by EMAILADDRESS=middleware@aaa.com, CN=AAA2-CA2A, OU=Security, O=AAA, L=Location, ST=YY, C=CO is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.l.a(l.java:65)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.l.b(l.java:92)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.k.a(k.java:5)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.jsse2.rc.a(rc.java:91)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.jsse2.rc.a(rc.java:69)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.jsse2.rc.checkServerTrusted(rc.java:6)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.jsse2.rc.b(rc.java:11)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.jsse2.mb.a(mb.java:646)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    ... 116 more
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by EMAILADDRESS=middleware@aaa.com, CN=AAA2-CA2A, OU=Security, O=AAA, L=Location, ST=YY, C=CO is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:411)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:258)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.l.a(l.java:137)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    ... 123 more
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by EMAILADDRESS=middleware@aaa.com, CN=AAA2-CA2A, OU=Security, O=AAA, L=Location, ST=YY, C=CO  is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:111)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.java:180)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.myValidator(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:737)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:649)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:357)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    ... 125 more
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.security.cert.CertPathUtil.findIssuer(CertPathUtil.java:317)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:108)
[08.02.18 16:18:37:213 CET] 0000002f SystemErr     R    ... 129 more
```

I already imported the certificate in:

**Security > SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates > NodeDefaultTrustStore > Signer certificates**

I also tried to import the root certificate but i cannot get rid of the error!!!

Comment: Was there an error in the longs telling you what truststore needed the certificate?  It would be in system out.    If that error is missing it's a pretty good indication the outbound connection is not being done by a WebSphere created SSLContext.  You can try adding the certificate to the JDK's cacerts file,  it could be that a the JDK's default SSLContext is being used in your scenario.

Comment: hi thansk for the suggestion. i'm developing inside RAD, where should i see the log, in the console? should i also raise Webshpere log levels?

Comment: I don't know how to get to the logs from within RAD.   Within WebSphere they are in  PROFILE_HOME/logs/<server>/SystemOut.log.   You would look for a message with ID of CWPKI0045E or CWPKI0022E.

Comment: thanks, i will start checking that out